# How to keep tests outside from source directory in Vite projects?

Tags: vue.js, vite, vitest

Running `npm init vue@latest` with the following setup

[image]

generates a Vitest spec file inside the `src` directory. I'm wondering why Cypress e2e tests have a seperate directory and Vitest unit tests are right next to the source code. Are there any reasons?

I want to move those tests to the root directory (equal to `cypress`), created a `vitest` directory and moved to spec into it.

The test itself passes but I think I have to change sopme configuration to exclude the tests from the build etc.

Inside the file `tsconfig.app.json` I changed the line `"exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],` to `"exclude": ["vitest"],`.

Is there something else I should do? Or are there any reasons to keep Vitest tests inside the source directory?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To get the test folder outside the source folder :

1. create a **vitest** folder on root dir
2. move `./src/components/__tests__` to `./vitest/__tests__`
3. On test ***.spec** file, you will import components with **alias** `@`

- `import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'`

4. in **tsconfig.app.json**

- change `"exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],` to `"exclude": ["vitest/**/__tests__/*"],`

5. run `npm run build && npm run test:unit`

---

> Would you mind explaining why you keep the **tests** directory inside the vitest directory?

You are not required to keep this folder. It's a convention, check below

If you want to put the **spec** file in the **tests** folder without a subfolder then just add to the `vite.config.ts` :

```
test: {
    include: ['./vitest/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}']
  }
```

then also adjust **tsconfig.app.json**: `"exclude": ["vitest/**/*"],`

Result of `yarn run test:unit`

[image]

Comment: @medsmh you don't necessarily need the `__tests__` folder now. That convention is mainly useful when unit tests are close to the src files (but adjust `exclude` if you remove it).

Comment: I'm not sure if I should stick to a `vitest` directory and move all those tests into it or if I should create a `tests` directory, move the generated cypress folder into it and create a `__tests__` directory for the Vitest stuff

Comment: I want to perform the same thing. I applied this solution. But it seems the `@` in imports is not resolved. Import cannot be found.

Comment: @Eria you need to define an alias. Check ‘resolve.alias’ in the vite doc and there: https://stackoverflow.com/a/66559769/774432

Comment: I have it already : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72468249/vitest-src-folder-alias-not-resolved-in-test-files

Comment: I found vscode didn't like this (when the vue project is in a subfolder anyway) and would mark the import as "not found" even though it worked when building/running tests.

To fix, I also had to add `"vitest/**/__tests__/*"` to the `includes` section in  **tsconfig.app.json**. It looks a bit odd, but works since **tsconfig.vitest.json** contains `"exclude": []"`, which clears the list of excludes. (the other option would be to duplicate the includes from **tsconfig.app.json** while adding `"vitest/**/__tests__/*"` there.

Answer (score 1):

on the latest release of vue 3, follow @flydev instruction and update your package.json file

from
 `"test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom --root src/",`

to

`"test:unit": "vitest --environment jsdom --root .",`