# Vitest - @ src folder alias not resolved in test files

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, vitest

I have a vue3 project using Vite/Vitest, as recommanded in Vue.js documentation.

Here is the structure of the project:

```
src
  components
    // my Vue components here, potentially in sub-folders. For example:
    HelloWorld.vue 
  router
    index.ts
  App.vue
  main.ts
vitest
  components
    // My test specs. For example:
    HelloWorld.spec.ts
// ...
tsconfig.app.json
tsconfig.json
tsconfig.vite-config.json
tsconfig.vitest.json
vite.config.ts
```

The `@/` alias for `src` folder is resolved properly in components files.
However, in my test files, I get an error: cannot find module.

For example, in `HelloWorld.spec.ts`:

```js
import HelloWorld from '@/components/HelloWorld.vue'; // <-- error !
import { describe, it } from 'vitest';

describe('HelloWorld', () => {
  it('should day hello', () => {
    // ...
  });
});
```

**tsconfig.app.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": [
    "env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "vitest/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

**vite.config.js**

```js
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';
import { fileURLToPath, URL } from 'url';
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': fileURLToPath(new URL('./src', import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
  test: {
    include: ['./vitest/**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}'],
  },
});
```

Comment: You could first try with a more standarized way to build aliases in **vite.config.js**: `alias: { "@": "./src" }` . If it's not working, or if you want to keep the same config, I suggest you to publish a **reproducible project**.

Comment: The alias config came as-is with the initialization of the project, using `npm init vue@latest`. But I tried other configs and none is working.

Comment: Yes - then you should give us a [reproducible project](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), i suspect a typescript config issue or it could be also possible that you hit a recent issue which require the project to be built at least one time before setting the `test.include`.

Comment: Do you also use a vitest.config.js file?

Comment: no, I don't use a specific config file for vitest

Comment: Any idea why we should exclude test files in `tsconfig.app.json`? Because including this files instead of excluding them solves the problem.

Comment: The reason is to avoid these files being compiled. You can be more "precise" about what you want to do with these files by using the typescript `configurations` option.

Comment: why is it a problem if the tests files are compiled?

Comment: same prob for me also. I tried to configure the `resolve.alias` vite config property but it still not working

Comment: @AdriHM, look at my comment of June 13. It may help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The final solution that worked for me was to include the test files in `tsconfig.vitest.json`:

**tsconfig.app.json** (*unchanged from question post*)

```json
{
  "extends": "@vue/tsconfig/tsconfig.web.json",
  "include": [
    "env.d.ts",
    "src/**/*",
    "src/**/*.vue"
  ],
  "exclude": [
    "vitest/**/*"
  ],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "@/*": [
        "./src/*"
      ]
    },
    "strict": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true
  }
}
```

**tsconfig.vitest.json**

```json
{
  "extends": "./tsconfig.app.json",
  "include": [
    "vitest/**/*",
  ],
  "exclude": [],
  "compilerOptions": {
    "composite": true,
    "lib": [],
    "types": [
      "node",
      "jsdom"
    ],
  }
}
```

Comment: Yep, worked for me as well, like include=[...., "test"] in the regular tsconfing.app.json

Answer (score 56):

You just have to specify the aliases in your `vitest.config.js` file:

```
import path from 'path'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

export default {
  plugins: [vue()],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      '@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src')
    },
  },
}
```

Comment: I guess it should be `'@': path.resolve(__dirname, './src'),`

Comment: oh yes you're right

Comment: This resolve option is not listed in their official documentation https://vitest.dev/config
Where do you find it ? ^^

Comment: I went to module sources lol, but I think it's here https://vitest.dev/config/#alias

Comment: It doesn't work. And it breaks half my existing unit tests.

Answer (score 6):

For SvelteKit users I ran into similar issue and had to add `$lib` to `vitest.config.js`

```
import { defineConfig } from 'vitest/config';
import { svelte } from '@sveltejs/vite-plugin-svelte';
import path from 'path';

export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [svelte({ hot: !process.env.VITEST })],
  test: {
    globals: true,
    environment: 'jsdom',
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      $lib: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/lib'),
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `vite-tsconfig-paths` plugin.

https://vitest.dev/guide/common-errors#cannot-find-module-relative-path

Answer (score 0):

I found that all I needed to do was add the file `web/tests/jsconfig.json`, given that my Vue + Typescript + Vitest front-end is located in the "web" folder of my project.

```json
// web/tests/jsconfig.json
// Helps VSCode detect typescript path aliases in test files
{
  "extends": "../tsconfig.json",
  "include": ["./**/*.test.ts"]
}
```

The missing include of the "tests/" folder seems to have been the primary issue, and the secondary issue was that VS Code couldn't detect the pathing.
The actual tests worked with the default https://vitejs.dev/guide/#trying-vite-online -> https://vite.new/vue-ts config, so I thought it made more sense to use a jsconfig.json to update VS Code's awareness rather than muck with the general tsconfig.json