# Aliases not resolved in vitest

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, vitest

I want to use aliases in tests files with `vitest`:

```
import { describe, expect, it } from 'vitest'
import Plan from '@/modules/Pricing/models/Plan'

let plan: Plan

describe('Plan model', () => {
  it('should bind properties correctly', () => {
    plan = new Plan({ id: 1234, name: 'columbo', price: 999 })

    expect(plan).toEqual({ id: 1234, name: 'columbo', price: 999 })
  })
})
```

It's a Nuxt app, I tried to configure the alias in `nuxt.config.ts`:

```
export default defineNuxtConfig({
  ssr: true,
  vite: {
    resolve: {
      alias: [
        { find: '@', replacement: path.resolve(__dirname, '.') }
      ]
    }
  },
// ...
})
```

When I start the test, I got this error:

[image]

Comment: I answer here for the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/a/73014028/10805872