# What is the intended test structure of vitest inside Vue projects?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vitest

I created a new Vue project via `npm init vue@latest` ( with **vitest** ). Inside `./src/components` is a `__test__` directory containing a component unit test.

Is it intended to create another `__test__` directory for the `./src/views` directory if you want to test your view files?

So when using a folder by type structure ( you might also want to use a folder by feature structure ) the project might look like

```
src
├── components
│   ├── MyComponent.vue
│   └── __test__
│       └── MyComponent.spec.vue
└── views
    ├── MyView1.vue
    ├── MyView2.vue
    └── __test__
        ├── MyView1.spec.vue
        └── MyView2.spec.vue
```

Please don't get me wrong, this is not a question about personal preferences . I just would like to know how vitest wants me to do it.

Because when having a `__test__` directory right next to my code, why wouldn't you put the spec files right next to the code and get rid of the directory?

E.g.

```
src
├── components
│   ├── MyComponent.vue
│   └── MyComponent.spec.vue
└── views
    ├── MyView1.vue
    ├── MyView1.spec.vue
    ├── MyView2.vue
    └── MyView2.spec.vue
```

It would be nice if one could explain the "common" way of using vitest inside Vue projects because until now I added a `test` directory right next to the `src` directory and mirrored the structure but it seems vitest/Vue prefers a different approach.

This might also be related to [How to keep tests outside from source directory in Vite projects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71219585/how-to-keep-tests-outside-from-source-directory-in-vite-projects) because to me it's not clear why someone would initialize a project with a `__test__` directory in the components directory only ( why not for views too? ) and add the line `"exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],` to the tsconfig.app.json file. What would happen if you keep your tests without having a `__test__` directory and have them outside the src directory or right next to your component/view/js/ts files?

Comment: Looks like you added a link to another question on this subject. I'm guessing you're hoping for a different answer than: *"it doesn't matter"*, which is, in fact, the case. Note the [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71263527/1891677) on the linked question confirms `__tests__` is a convention: *"You are not required to keep this folder. It's a convention[...]"*

Comment: @tao yes you are right. I think I should change my question to: After setting up a fresh new project, what needs to be done if `vitest tests should live inside the root dir in a vitest dir` or `vitest tests should live right next to the code` or `vitest tests live inside a __test__ directory in each directory`

Comment: Before you ask what needs to be done, you have to define the intended outcome. If the intended outcome is: "*so nothing breaks and `vitest` works as intended*", then the answer is: *"Nothing needs to be done. You can place your tests inside the components folder directly. `vitest` will run them"*

Comment: You say don't understand why someone would create a `__tests__` folder in `components`, but not in `views`. Because the person who made that template was not consistent. Most likely, they made the folder in `components` to avoid clutter (because that folder typically gets a lot of files). `views` rarely has more than 10 files (typically 2-5), so the need to unclutter it is smaller. But I can't definitively answer your question, because I don't know who put that there and what they were thinking. I suggest you ask it on Vue's discord channel, although I doubt you'll get a definitive answer.

Answer (score 9):

The short answer is: `vitest` *does not **care** where you put your files*. It is un-opinionated and it doesn't have an intended folder structure. It will run any tests it finds.

---

The default value of `include` (which determines where `vitest` looks for test files) is:

```js
  include: [ '**/*.{test,spec}.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}' ],
```

You can inspect it by running

```js
include { defaultConfig } from 'vitest/config'

console.log(defaultConfig.include);
```

in your `vitest.config.file`.

It includes any file, in any folder, ending in `.test` or `.spec` immediately followed by `.{js,mjs,cjs,ts,mts,cts,jsx,tsx}`.

An easy way to test is to move your test files around. You'll notice they'll still be picked up when running tests.

---

Your template came with `__test__` folders ***only*** because whoever put that template together thought it would be cleaner to have tests in separate folders. That's opinionated.

If you have a different opinion, `vitest` will still work, seamlessly.

The common patterns for test files are:

- test inside the component's folder (typically associated with each component having its own folder). This pattern is slightly more popular in Angular and React worlds)
- tests inside a root `tests` folder, which mimics the entire project's folder (slightly more popular in Vue world)
- tests inside multiple `__tests__` folders, one for each project folder. (I've seen this in a few projects, not necessarily associated with one framework or another).

All of the above are opinionated and `vitest` will work with any, making no difference.

Personal advice: try out each pattern for at least 6 months, you might notice minor differences in how you work. You might end up liking one more over the others and it might feel like you're more efficient using it. That's the pattern for you.

Unless you're in a team, of course, and you need to agree with the rest of the team on the pattern. In 90% of the cases, the most senior dev in the team will set the pattern.

Comment: do you know why it excludes the vitest tests in the tsconfig.app.json? ( `"exclude": ["src/**/__tests__/*"],` ) . When having the spec files right next to the code, there will be no `__tests__` directory anymore so one might remove this line. But what is its purpose? Because I think TS must be able to compile it, no?

Comment: @Question3r, if you look into `tsconfig.vitest.json`, it extends `tsconfig.app.json` and overrides `exclude` with an empty array. I believe this means: any ts errors in test files should be ignored by build/serve. Should only be considered when testing. You might get a better answer in Vue's discord "vue-3-advanced" channel. I haven't used tsconfig references before.